# Programatically creating a user not appearing in Users index table

Tags: plugin-development, users

I'm trying to programatically create a user (once the user submits a form through Sprout Forms). The user doesn't seem to appear in the Users section of the CP.

I've ensured the user is being added correctly - I can even see a row in the craft_users database table. Going directly to admin/users/349 (the ID of the newly added user) shows all the user details.

It's been suggested that I need to index the new element data - but not sure how to do this.

```
$content = $entry->getContent();

$user = new UserModel();
$user->username         = $content['email'];
$user->email            = $content['email'];
$user->unverifiedEmail  = $content['email'];
$user->firstName        = $content['firstName'];
$user->lastName         = $content['lastName'];
$user->newPassword      = $content['password'];
$user->pending          = true;

$success = craft()->users->saveUser($user);

if ($success) {
    craft()->search->indexElementAttributes($user);

    // Assign them to the default user group
    craft()->userGroups->assignUserToDefaultGroup($user);

    // Send the activation email
    craft()->users->sendActivationEmail($user);

    // Update the Element Index
    craft()->search->indexElementAttributes($user);
}
```

Comment: FWIW, `craft()->search->indexElementAttributes()` shouldn't be necessary here. If you look at the `id` column for the user in the `craft_users` table, do you have a matching `elementId` in `craft_elements_i18n` and `id` in `craft_elements`?

Comment: Hey Brad - yeah I didn't think I'd need it. I have a matching row in both `craft_elements_i18n` and `craft_elements`. Both have `enabled` set to 1.

Comment: Probably worth glancing through `craft\app\controllers\UsersController->actionSaveUser()` just to make sure you're not missing a piece of info before `craft()->users->saveUser()` gets called.

Comment: @BradBell, yep, thats where I started. Will have another look through!

Comment: @BradBell I've just copy/pasted the code from `actionSaveUser()`, even adding the private methods, and still the same result. Very strange. Are there any caches to be emptied or something?

Comment: I just tried your example virtually line for line (minus `$content = $entry->getContent();` and `indexElementAttributes`) and it's working fine for me.

Comment: @BradBell - Ah, figured it out...

Comment: Ahh... nice catch.  Probably worth adding as an official answer?

Answer (score 2):

For anyone's future benefit - this happens due to the fact I'm adding the user in the `sproutForms.saveEntry` hook. That happens after it messes around with the `fieldContext` and `contentTable` options for the Entry. As such, the user is getting saved to the wrong context, so it won't appear...

A quick workaround for this is to move the following lines in `SproutForms_EntriesService.php:133-135` to lines 120. This resets the field context back before the hook is called.

```
if ($transaction !== null)
{
    $transaction->commit();

    SproutFormsPlugin::log('Transaction committed');
}

// Reset our field context and content table to what they were previously
craft()->content->fieldContext = $oldFieldContext;
craft()->content->contentTable = $oldContentTable;

Craft::import('plugins.sproutforms.events.SproutForms_OnSaveEntryEvent');

$event = new SproutForms_OnSaveEntryEvent(
    $this, array(
        'entry'      => $entry,
        'isNewEntry' => $isNewEntry,
        'event'      => 'saveEntry',
        'entity'     => $entry,
    )
);

craft()->sproutForms->onSaveEntry($event);
```

Comment: This has been fixed in Sprout Forms v1.0.1